# Wiring between two child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and I have a specific example of trying to wire two components together through an interface. I have read most of the parent/child, child/parent and sibling component communication stackoverflow related questions and can't seem to find a proper answer.

Say I have an App component that renders a Box and a Mover component. Quite simply, the Box has a move(x,y) function that I'd like the Mover to interface. However, the Mover doesn't have to be a child of Box (or any other relationship) -- specifically, I don't want the Box to pass down its own methods to the Mover.

What I'd like to do in the App, is something like this:

```
...
render: function() {
    return (
        <Box ref="box"/>
        <Mover box = {this.refs.box} />
    )
}
....
```

However, you can't use refs in render() as clearly indicated in the docs and the box refs isn't defined anyways until it's mounted (so the box props won't work).

I've thought of using an intermediate object:

```
...
render: function() {
    var api = {box: undefined};
    return (
        <Box api={api}/>
        <Mover api={api} />
    )
}
....
```

Where Box sets itself in this.props.api in its componentDidMount method, but that's a little iffy. Another option would be to use the refs callback in the App to do the wiring, but that requires ugly glue code.

Is there any other way to pass references to (yet uncreated) components between each other when rendering them? Or is there some more general design principle that I'm not adhering to?

Comment: I think the general idea is to pass a function to from parent down to Box. Box would then invoke that callback so that the parent could affect Mover.

Comment: `var box = <Box />;  return (<div>{ box }<Mover box={ box } /></div>);`

Comment: @WiredPrairie I actually tried this, but inside the Mover I can't seem to call box.move(). Debugging indicates that box is an instance of ReactElement and doesn't have the move method.

Comment: Yes -- that wouldn't give you direct access to the inner instance. You really should be triggering a property update to the container which would then update the two elements.

Answer (score 3):

For siblings, you generally need to move whatever state they both need to reference up into a common parent component and pass it down as props (or sideways into an external storage object - see react-training's [Less Simple Communication](https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-training/blob/gh-pages/lessons/04-less-simple-communication.md) lesson for an example) and pass it to them as props.

e.g. if the component rendering `Box` and `Mover` had the following state:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  }
}
```

Then you could pass `Mover` a callback function which updates it:

```
handleMove: function(x, y) {
  this.setState({x: x, y: y})
}

// within render() - you could also pass x and y if Mover needs them
<Mover onMove={this.handleMove}/>

// within Mover
this.props.onMove(newX, newY)
```

If you passed this state to `Box` as props, it wouldn't necessarily need an explicit `move()` method (depending on what it does) but could either use the props in its `render()` method (which would automatically re-render when the props change), or you could react to the `x` and `y` values changing by detecting the change with a `componentWillReceiveProps()` method:

```
// within render()
<Box x={this.state.x} y={this.state.y}/>

// within Box
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.x !== this.props.x || nextProps.y !== this.props.y) {
    // ...
  }
}
```